# Ansible : Make templates use variables defined in different file for different run

Tags: ansible

I have a task in playbook as shown :

```
- name: Create configuration.json for every analytics from the template.
  template:
    src: ./src-zip/{{ item.key }}/configuration_sample.j2
    dest: ./src-zip/{{ item.key }}/configuration.json
  with_dict: "{{ apps }}"
```

Now , i have variables in which some are common and some are different defined in file for every run .

Like, there is file `var_alerts-manager.yml` for one run.
For another run, I have `var_abc.yml`.

Now i want to use different file for different run. In other words, template will use variables defined in `var_alerts-manager.yml` in one run and `abc.yml` in another run and so on.

How can this be achieved in ansible and where should I keep these files so task can include only that specific file for every run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scenario for which roles mechanism evolved:

1. Create a `my_role` role in your playbook dir.
2. Move your task and template into that role.
3. Store your variables inside `vars` directory in the role.
4. Execute the role with:

   ```
   - name: Create configuration.json for every analytics from the template.
     include_role:
       name: my_role
       vars_from: "{{ item.key }}"  # or whatever key your naming is defined in
     loop: "{{ apps|dict2items }}"
   ```

<sup>You might want to replace `item` inside the template task with some other variable for clarity, read about [`loop_control`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control).</sup>